# How can I handle multiple pages with the same loop Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I'm trying to handle elements from multiple pages via the same loop after click `next` button like on website:

```
        driver.get("https://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php?country=UA&page=1");
        List<Journal> journalList = new ArrayList<>();

        WebElement tableId = driver.findElement(By.tagName("table"));
        List<WebElement> trElements = tableId.findElements(By.xpath("./tbody/tr"));

        //...

        for (int i = 0; i < count / 50; i++) {
            for (int id = 1; id <= trElements.size(); id++) {
                for (WebElement element : trElements) {
                    String title = element.findElement(By.xpath("./td[2]/a")).getText();
                    String country = "Ukraine";
                    journalList.add(new Journal(id, title, country));
                    id++;
                }
            }
            WebElement element = driver.findElementByXPath("(//div[@class='pagination_buttons']/a)[2]");
            element.click();
        }
```

The problem is this loop is going through the first page only one time. When I click `next` button on line:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElementByXPath("(//div[@class='pagination_buttons']/a)[2]");
```

looks like variable: `trElements`, which I'm getting, isn't updating and I can't go again through same loop on the `next` page.

Can someone show me an example how to handle multiple pages via the same loop dynamically? No matter how many pages website will have.

*But I'd prefer to handle pages while the next button is clickable.*

Updated:

```
        driver.get("https://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php?country=UA&page=1");
        List<Journal> journalList = new ArrayList<>();

        //...

        for (int i = 0; i < count / 50; i++) {
            WebElement tableId = driver.findElement(By.tagName("table"));
            List<WebElement> trElements = tableId.findElements(By.xpath("./tbody/tr"));

            for (int id = 1; id <= trElements.size(); id++) {
                WebElement element = trElements.get(id);
                String title = element.findElement(By.xpath("./td[2]/a")).getText();
                String country = "Ukraine";
                journalList.add(new Journal(id, title, country));

            }
            WebElement element = driver.findElementByXPath("(//div[@class='pagination_buttons']/a)[2]");
            element.click();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you do `element.click();` your DOM gets rebuilt so after that you have your `trElements` stayed filled with stale elements.

I would recommend to bring your `List<WebElement> trElements = tableId.findElements(By.xpath("./tbody/tr"));` into the `i`-loop. There is also not much value in your inner loop hence you can do it with in your `id`-loop using the approach like:

```java
String title = trElements.get(id-1).findElement(By.xpath("./td[2]/a")).getText();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about rebuilding DOM, Alexey R. I'll try your approach and, if it helps me, I'll mark your answer as acceptable.